# doubts on the meaning of the auxiliary verb "do"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the "seventh Hymn on the Nativity", where St. Ephraim speaks about Tamar (Genesis 38), I read:  "She was a widow for your sake. **You did she long for**, she hasted and was also a harlot for your sake. **You did she vehemently desire**.

Is that some typo? what do those two sentences mean?
Thank you.

Comment: This is not Modern English. This is deliberately archaized Early Modern English, and its syntax is not current. That's for starts. Don't expect 400-year-old writing to have typos -- the language and the writing were both different from the way they are now.

Answer (score 5):

There is a stylistic [inversion](https://www.thoughtco.com/inversion-grammar-term-1691193) or *fronting* at play where the direct object has been placed at the front of the sentence, breaking the expectation of Subject-Verb-Object order for emphasis.

> She was a widow for your sake. You did she long for, she hasted and was also a harlot for your sake. You did she vehemently desire.

```
"You did she long for" -> "She did long for you." 
"You did she vehemently desire" -> "She vehemently desired you."
```

The "you" acquires more precedence and weight. In this kind of fronting, the auxiliary verb directly follows the fronted object, just as would happen with a question [where a wh-form was fronted](http://folk.uio.no/hhasselg/Gr2-ch11a.html):

```
"Who did she long for?" -> "She did long for you."
```

Comment: Thank you so much, TaliesinMerlin.  I would never have been able to figure it out by myself.